# Multiple slideshows, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, fullpage.js

i'm using the  [VERTICAL SHOWCASE SLIDER](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/01/vertical-showcase-slider-with-jquery-and-css-transitions/) as a jQuery Plugin in my [FULLPAGE.JS](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master) webpage. 
When I use the Vertical slider once, there is no problem. But if i insert the code twice in another section of fullpage, the second slider doesn't work.

1.st slider

```
<div class="section " id="section1">

    <section id="ps-container" class="ps-container">
    <div class="ps-header">
            <h1><br></h1>
        </div><!-- /ps-header -->

        <div class="ps-contentwrapper">

            <div class="ps-content">
                <h3>ESPAÑA</h3> <h2>Alex SAMPEDRO</h2>
                <p>With restful springiness in the seat; prevents static sitting and provides enhanced seating comfort. Padded seat and back for enhanced seating comfort. Soft, hardwearing and easy care leather, which ages gracefully.</p>
                <!--<a href="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/80163804/#/60203882">Buy this item</a>-->
            </div>

            <div class="ps-content">
                <h3>CHILE</h3> <h2>Keno PARRA</h2>
                <p>For increased stability, re-tighten the screws about two weeks after assembly. Seat and back with restful flexibility; prevents a static sitting posture and enhances comfort.</p>
            </div>



        </div><!-- /ps-contentwrapper -->

        <div class="ps-slidewrapper">

            <div class="ps-slides">
                <div style="background-image:url(CIMA/Oradores/AlexSampedro.jpg);"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url(CIMA/Oradores/AlexSampedro.jpg);"></div>


            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="ps-prev" ></a>
                <a href="#" class="ps-next" ></a>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /ps-slidewrapper -->

    </section><!-- /ps-container -->

    <!-- jQuery if needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider_slide.js"></script>
```

2nd slider:

```
 <div class="section " id="section2">

    <section id="ps-container" class="ps-container">
    <div class="ps-header">
            <h1><br></h1>
        </div><!-- /ps-header -->

        <div class="ps-contentwrapper">

            <div class="ps-content">
                <h3>ESPAÑA</h3> <h2>Alex SAMPEDRO</h2>
                <p>With restful springiness in the seat; prevents static sitting and provides enhanced seating comfort. Padded seat and back for enhanced seating comfort. Soft, hardwearing and easy care leather, which ages gracefully.</p>
                <!--<a href="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/80163804/#/60203882">Buy this item</a>-->
            </div>

            <div class="ps-content">
                <h3>CHILE</h3> <h2>Keno PARRA</h2>
                <p>For increased stability, re-tighten the screws about two weeks after assembly. Seat and back with restful flexibility; prevents a static sitting posture and enhances comfort.</p>
            </div>



        </div><!-- /ps-contentwrapper -->

        <div class="ps-slidewrapper">

            <div class="ps-slides">
                <div style="background-image:url(CIMA/Oradores/AlexSampedro.jpg);"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url(CIMA/Oradores/AlexSampedro.jpg);"></div>


            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="ps-prev" ></a>
                <a href="#" class="ps-next" ></a>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /ps-slidewrapper -->

    </section><!-- /ps-container -->

    <!-- jQuery if needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider_slide.js"></script>
```

What can I do that both work?

Comment: please post a fiddlr or plunkr

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: What's in `js/slider_slide.js` ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/iKwhRu6D4khyfpcNaQLb
i have not attached all the js and css files. the thing is: i can see both slideshows, but if i click "next" on the second, it changes the image of the first. i think it is a general problem of multiple slideshows.... 
if you need the whole code, ill uploade my folder